# Segmentation Fault Point

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing Algorithm code for removing similar character.
For Ex. If input string is "abb" Output should be "a" and for "abcddbf" string output should be "acf".

I have written some code as mentioned below but some how I am getting Segmentation Faut and I am not able to find the faulty point.

Code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *remove_adjecent_string(char *in,int count)
{
int i=0;
int j=0;
int flag = 0;
int total = strlen(in);
static char *output = NULL;

if(count == 0)
{
    output=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*total);
    if(output == NULL)
    {
            return NULL;
    }
    for(i=0,j=0;i<=total;i++)
    {
            if(in[i] != '*')
            {
                    output[j]=in[i];
                    j++;
            }
    }
    return (char *)output;
}

for(i=0;i<=count;++i)
{ 
    printf("In loop i  :%d count :%d \t",i,count);
    printf("Before comparition in[i] = %c , in[count] = %c \t",in[i],in[count]);
    if(in[i] == in[count])
    {
            printf("Same found in[%d]  = in[%d] = %c",i,count,in[i]);
            in[i]='*';
            flag = 1;
    }
    printf(" Next loop i = %d\n",++i);
}

printf("Before Recursion \n");
output =remove_adjecent_string(in,(count-1));
return (char *)output;
}


int main()
{
  char *input;
  char *output;
  int i=0;
  input = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
  if(input == NULL)
  {
          return;
  }
  output=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
  if(output == NULL)
  {
          return;
  }
  input = "abbb";
  int  count = -1;
  count=strlen(input);
  output=remove_adjecent_string(input,(count-1));
  printf("Input String = %s\n",input);
  printf("Output String = %s\n",output);

}
```

Help me to find out the faulty case.

Comment: If you can't use a debugger, put printf statements after each block of non-trivial code. Whatever prints before the segfault is okay. You can keep adding printf statements as needed until you can identify the line that causes the segfault.

Comment: Use gdb and see which line gives segmentation fault and you might get why thats happening.

Comment: always allocate used length +1 (for the \0)

Comment: Compile your code. Run your executable with gdb. As the exectuable exits with SEGMENTATION FAULT. Type `'bt'` in `gdb` to see which line caused the segmentation fault.

Comment: I understand why people cast the return value of `malloc()` from `void *` to `char *`. **But seriously, why cast `char *` to `char *`?** As in `char *output; return (char *)output`...

Comment: As you see I have tried to narrow down the point of segmentation using some debug logs but still I am not able to see the exact point.As per my debugging whenever for (i=0;i<count;++i) reaches i=1 point ( for my example input string "abb" I am getting segmentation fault.

Comment: @user2767620 And how does a no-op (typecast) help with that?

Answer (score 4):

```
    input = "abbb";
```

so input points to a const string which is not modifiable. it will segv when you try to write to it:

```
    in[i]='*';
```

add: you seem to want to copy "abbb" to input so consider using strncpy()

Answer (score 0):

How to find segfaults:

1. Add debugging symbols to your executable. If you use g++ or gcc, add the `-g`-option to the compiler command line.
2. Run the program in a debugger: `gdb --args ./your-program [args]` for gdb and linux.
3. Type `r` to run the program.
4. Wait for the segfault to accur
5. Type `bt` to print the call stack. Find the topmost line that is in your code and take the filename and line number.
6. Have a close look at that line.

Answer (score 0):

Something I detected is that `remove_adjecent_string()` returns a buffer (named `output`) containing a string, but between `malloc`ing and populating this buffer, at no moment it makes sure its a proper [null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) (`\0` after the last character). In fact you don't even alloc enought space for that.

Depending on the situation, this may cause your `printf()` to print memory garbage and even cause segmentation fault, because it will keep printing whatever is in the memory after your buffer until it finally finds a null byte lost somewhere.